# TypeError: invalid type promotion when running my model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have build my model using custom transformers as below:

The sample data is

```
ID columnA     columnB columnC columnD   columnE   columnF
2  2017-02-03   nan      5       GOLD     12000     -56
4  2019-06-12   50      456     SILVER     500       70
```

This is the build model script which imports the custom preprocessors and runs them in a pipeline

```
import os
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from config import DATA_DIR,DTYPES, GRID_PARAMS, X_TRAIN,Y_TRAIN,X_TEST,Y_TEST
from transformers import (MissingTreatmentDate,MissingTreatment,DateExtractor,EngineerFeatures)


#function to load data
def load_dataset(x_path, y_path):
    x = pd.read_csv(os.sep.join([DATA_DIR, x_path]),
                    dtype=DTYPES,
                    index_col="ID",
                    parse_dates=['columnA']
                    )
    y = pd.read_csv(os.sep.join([DATA_DIR, y_path]))

    return x, y

 def build_model():
        preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([("missingTreatmentDate",MissingTreatmentDate(),['columnA']),
                                              ("missingTreatment",MissingTreatment(),['columnB','columnC']),
                                              ("categories",OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown="ignore"),["columnD"]),
                                              ("dates",DateExtractor(),["columnA"]),
                                              ("feateng",EngineerFeatures(),["columnE","columnF"])])

            #include the preprocessor and the predictive model
            model = Pipeline([("preprocessor", preprocessor),
                              ("model",LogisticRegression())])

            return model
```

I then validate if the model is working using the below query

```
X_train, y_train = load_dataset("X_train.zip", "y_train.zip")
from model import build_model

model = build_model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.predict(X_train)
```

but i get the below error

```
~\.conda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
315                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
316                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 317                 **fit_params_steps[name])
318             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
319             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer
<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Comment: Can you please post your code, the first part is confusing. There is return model command but there is no function.

Comment: @HarishVutukuri I have included the entire script